# could not launch the emualator please file an issue an attempt was made to load an application with an incorect format

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator

I get this error when trying to launch xamarin emulator from visual studio 2017 device manager. I have downloaded image file tried resetting but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have encounted similar problems, and my solutin are:
1)check the Complile Android version,Minimum Android version,Target Android version and the OS for your divice(You can get this by opening ADM and editing the device). Please sure you have intalled the SDK for the compiling version, target version and the device OS by Android ADK Manager.
2) If you have correctly installed the needed ADK and still get the problem, you can install the app on your phone and run the project again.